# Transformar a uint16_t

Tags: c++, arduino

Estoy desarrollando un código de programación para ESP8266. 
En este, se almacena en un archivo en SPIFFS el código RAW del artefacto que deseo accionar.
Un ejemplo del archivo que tengo almacenado en SPIFFS es:

```
3480, 1760, 400, 444, 424, 1308, 420, 444, 424, 444, 424, 440, 424, 440, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 448, 444, 420, 444, 420, 448, 420, 1332, 400, 444, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 420, 1332, 400, 1332, 396, 1312, 420, 444, 452, 440, 424, 1308, 420, 448, 420, 444, 420, 444, 420, 448, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 440, 424, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 448, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 444, 420, 448, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 448, 448, 440, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 1336, 396, 1332, 400, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 10008, 3484, 1736, 404, 440, 424, 1308, 448, 448, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 440, 424, 444, 420, 444, 424, 440, 424, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 1332, 400, 444, 424, 440, 452, 444, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 440, 424, 444, 424, 1304, 424, 1332, 400, 1308, 424, 440, 424, 444, 420, 1332, 400, 444, 424, 440, 424, 440, 424, 444, 424, 440, 448, 444, 424, 440, 424, 444, 424, 440, 424, 444, 420, 444, 424, 440, 424, 444, 424, 440, 424, 440, 424, 444, 424, 1308, 420, 1308, 424, 1308, 424, 440, 452, 440, 424, 440, 428, 440, 424, 1308, 424, 1304, 424, 444, 424, 1304, 424, 444, 424, 440, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 436, 428, 440, 428, 436, 456, 436, 428, 1304, 424, 1308, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 428, 1300, 428, 1304, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 452, 440, 424, 440, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 424, 440, 428, 440, 424, 1308, 424, 1300, 432, 1304, 452, 440, 424, 440, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 1328, 404, 1304, 428, 1304, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 452, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 428, 436, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 1304, 452, 440, 428, 436, 428, 1304, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 1304, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 452, 440, 428, 436, 428, 436, 428, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 428, 1300, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 1300, 428, 440, 428, 436, 456, 1324, 408
```

El código del aire declarado en el código sin estar en SPIFFS se vería así:

```
uint16_t powerOff[439] = {3480, 1760, 400, 444, 424, 1308, 420, 444, 424, 444, 424, 440, 424, 440, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 448, 444, 420, 444, 420, 448, 420, 1332, 400, 444, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 420, 1332, 400, 1332, 396, 1312, 420, 444, 452, 440, 424, 1308, 420, 448, 420, 444, 420, 444, 420, 448, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 440, 424, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 448, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 444, 420, 448, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 448, 448, 440, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 1336, 396, 1332, 400, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 10008, 3484, 1736, 404, 440, 424, 1308, 448, 448, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 440, 424, 444, 420, 444, 424, 440, 424, 444, 420, 444, 424, 444, 420, 444, 420, 1332, 400, 444, 424, 440, 452, 444, 420, 444, 420, 444, 424, 440, 424, 444, 424, 1304, 424, 1332, 400, 1308, 424, 440, 424, 444, 420, 1332, 400, 444, 424, 440, 424, 440, 424, 444, 424, 440, 448, 444, 424, 440, 424, 444, 424, 440, 424, 444, 420, 444, 424, 440, 424, 444, 424, 440, 424, 440, 424, 444, 424, 1308, 420, 1308, 424, 1308, 424, 440, 452, 440, 424, 440, 428, 440, 424, 1308, 424, 1304, 424, 444, 424, 1304, 424, 444, 424, 440, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 436, 428, 440, 428, 436, 456, 436, 428, 1304, 424, 1308, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 428, 1300, 428, 1304, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 452, 440, 424, 440, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 424, 440, 428, 440, 424, 1308, 424, 1300, 432, 1304, 452, 440, 424, 440, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 1328, 404, 1304, 428, 1304, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 452, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 428, 436, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 1304, 452, 440, 428, 436, 428, 1304, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 1304, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 452, 440, 428, 436, 428, 436, 428, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 436, 428, 440, 428, 1300, 428, 440, 424, 440, 428, 1300, 428, 440, 428, 436, 456, 1324, 408};
```

Pero precisamente la idea es grabarlos en SPIFFS para poderlos cambiar en cualquier momento y sobre todo ahorrar espacio en la ESP, la cual se me está quedando corta de memoria, y solo cargar el código IR cuando se vaya a mandar y sea necesario.

Probé lo siguiente (no me dio resultados):

Primera prueba:

```
bool SPIFFSCodes::loadPowerOff() 
{
    File file_id= SPIFFS.open("/powerOff", "r");
    if (!file_id) 
    {
        Serial.println("Failed to open powerOff file");
        return false;
    }

    size_t size = file_id.size();
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[size]);
    file_id.readBytes(buf.get(), size);
    uint16_t powerOff[439];
    for (int i = 0; i != 439; i++)
    {
        powerOff[i] = 256*buf[2*i]+buf[2*i+1];
    }
    // show the data in console and check if it is correct:
    for (int i = 0; i != 439; i++)
    {
        Serial.print(powerOff[i]); 
        Serial.print(", ");
    }
    irsend1.sendRaw(powerOff,439,38);
    return true;
}
```

Segunda prueba:

```
bool SPIFFSCodes::loadPowerOff() 
{
    File file_id= SPIFFS.open("/powerOff", "r");
    if (!file_id) 
    {
        Serial.println("Failed to open powerOff file");
        return false;
    }

    size_t size = file_id.size();
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[size]);
    file_id.readBytes(buf.get(), size);
    uint16_t powerOff[439];
    for (int i = 0; i != 439; i++)
    {
        powerOff[i] = buf[2*i]+64*buf[2*i+1];
    }
    // show the data in console and check if it is correct:
    for (int i = 0; i != 439; i++)
    {
        Serial.print(powerOff[i]); 
        Serial.print(", ");
    }
    irsend1.sendRaw(powerOff,439,38);
    return true;
}
```

Ambas dieron resultados con valores erróneos y muy altos al que debería ser. Necesito que la salida sea en uint16_t dado que es el tipo de dato que necesita la librería IR para mandar la señal.

Comment: El contenido del archivo ... ¿ es texto separado por comas y espacios, o son datos crudos sin separación ? En este último caso ¿ están en el Endian adecuado ?

Comment: Está separado por comas y espacios, seria algo así: 3457, 7836, 7777, ....

Comment: No sabría decirle el tema del Endian, soy principiante, espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de nada: **no** tengo el *hardware*/*software* para probarlo, así que esto puede necesitar algunos *retoques* para funcionar correctamente.

Si tu archivo es de texto ... ¿ Porqué lo estás tratando como si fueran datos crudos ( *raw* ) ?

```
for ( int i = 0; i != 439; i++ ) {
  powerOff[i] = 256 * buf[2 * i] + buf[2 * i + 1];
}
```

Eso solo tendría sentido si `buf[]` contuviera ya la representación binaria de los números, pero no es así. `buf[]` contiene **los caracteres ASCII** que has cargado del archivo.

Tienes que *parsear* el archivo primero, y después convertirlo a `uint16_t`. Por suerte, tus códigos numéricos no incluyen el `0`, por lo que es bastante simple:

```
#define POWEROFF_SIZE 439

bool SPIFFSCodes::loadPowerOff( ) {
  File file_id = SPIFFS.open( "/powerOff", "r" );

  if( !file_id ) {
    Serial.println( "Failed to open powerOff file" );
    return false;
  }

  uint16_t powerOff[POWEROFF_SIZE];
  long value;
  int index = 0;

  while( ( value = file_id.parseInt( ) ) ) {
    // Por si acaso ...
    if( value < 0 ) {
      Serial.println( "Negative value: " );
      Serial.println( value );
      return false;
    }
    if( value > 65535L ) {
      Serial.println( "Too big value: " );
      Serial.println( value );
      return false;
    }

    powerOff[index] = (uint16_t)value;
    ++index;
  }

  if( index != POWEROFF_SIZE ) {
    Serial.println( "Error reading/parsing powerOff file. Readed values: " );
    Serial.println( index );
    return false;
  }

  for( index = 0; index != POWEROFF_SIZE; ++index ) {
    Serial.print( powerOff[index] ); 
    Serial.print( ", " );
  }

  irsend1.sendRaw( powerOff, POWEROFF_SIZE, 38 );

  return true;
}
```

<sub>Nota: este código debe de tardar algo mas de 1 segundo en leer/interpretar el archivo, debido a como funciona `Stream.parseInt( )`. Se podría acelerar, pero así es mas simple.</sub>

Eso te debería mostrar el contenido del archivo por tu línea serie, o bien algún mensaje de error.

Comment: Hay una pequeña parte que tuve que modificar, del resto todo excelente!
Muchas gracias!

Comment: @GiampaoloManeri Vale, he visto la edición; es lo que pasa al no poder probarlo, que se cuelan *gazapos*. Me alegra que te sirviera :-)

Comment: No se preocupe, muchas gracias. Es usted muy amable!